# Why does this script not work on imported models

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I've created a movement script that checks to see if an object is grounded, and if so, moves the object based on user input. When I attach it to an object I create in Unity, it works. When I attach it to an object I created in Blender and then imported, nothing. No errors, the object just fails to respond. I can't figure out what is causing the imported object to not respond to input. Both objects have a rigidbody and a collider.

This is the code for movement:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed = 10f;
public float rotationSpeed = 100f;

private float distToGround;
private Collider collider;


void Start() {
    collider = GetComponent<Collider>();
    distToGround = collider.bounds.extents.y;
}

void Update() {
    MovePlayer();
}

void MovePlayer() {
    float translation = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    float rotation = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    if (translation != null && rotation != null) {
        if (IsGrounded()) {
            transform.Translate(0, 0, translation * speed * Time.deltaTime);
            transform.Rotate(0, rotation * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        }
    }
}

bool IsGrounded() {
    return Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector3.up, distToGround + 0.1f);
}
```

}

I've made a video demonstrating this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qatBF5Ov3Zo&feature=youtu.be

Comment: A .blend file? Any chance you can host a repro project somewhere? Or otherwise supply screenshots of your component setup?

Comment: I've been playing with this since posting and think I have found the problem. It's the Unity axis vs Blender axis. If I import my object with it's front facing down and it's rear in the air, the object moves as the script dictates. It looks like I need to somehow make the z axis on my tank point forward, at the moment it's pointing up.

Comment: Ah yep, that may very well be. They use different coordinate systems. I believe fbx export may have an option to transform on export, but I'm not 100% certain. Perhaps try that route?

Comment: I feel a bit dumb now. That was absolutely the issue. I found the main object had the right orientation while the child objects have their Z pointing up instead of forward. I added a rigidbody and collider to the main object and now the script works. Looks like I just need to be sure that exported Blender objects are facing the Z and not the Y.

Comment: No worries, glad it's solved. That is something we all encounter at some point.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complication caused by Blender left handed axis vs Unity's right handed axis. When I exported a rotated object from Blender, the script works on the object as expected. The solution is to make sure that the object you are exporting is facing the Z axis instead of the native Y axis.